# Allow only login to Firebase using Admin SDK Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase Auth to sign in my users and want to know how can I use Admin SDK to create new users and only let those users sign in to my app. This should not let users sign up by themselves. As I need to start using Admin SDK, can you also tell me how to start using it and how to solve my problem

Comment: You can use firebase cloud functions.

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of function can I write for my purpose, because what I want  to achieve is signup users by cloud functions and let them login then only? @SushantSomani

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to create users using `email` and `password`.
Writing an export function in `firebase` will create user for you.
You just have to call that function from the client side, like your `android` app.

```
import * as admins from 'firebase-admin';
const admin = admins.auth();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{ \
   const email:string = data.email;
   const password:string = data.password;
   const displayName:string= data.displayName;

   return createUser(email,false,password,displayName,false).then(function(userRecord){
      console.log("User Created: "+userRecord.email);
})
});


createUser(email:string, emailVerified:boolean,password:string, displayName:string, disabled:boolean):Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    admin.createUser({
      email: email,
    emailVerified: emailVerified,
    password: password,
    displayName: displayName,
    disabled: disabled
   }).then(function(userRecord){
     resolve(userRecord);
   }).catch(function(error){
     console.log("Error: "+error.message)
     reject(error.message)
   })
  });
}
```

Deploy the above code to `firebase` cloud functions and then call the method `createUser` from the `Android` app.